# PhantomJS, Capybara, Poltergeist failed to reach server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I'm working with poltergeist for the first time, so I don't really know what I'm doing but I couldn't find any solution on the web. Please tell me if any information is missing.

Error message:

> Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError: Request failed to reach
>   server, check DNS and/or server status

this issue doesn't happen on production but only on development and staging environment.

This line of code is the one that is making the trouble

```
phantomjs_options: ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--ssl-protocol=any', '--load-images=no', '--proxy=localhost:9050', '--proxy-type=socks5']
```

without '--proxy=localhost:9050' everything's working perfectly on every environment but I don't want to delete it in case it's critical for the production.

**I've also noticed that on staging/development there's no 9050 port listening but on production there is one**

full config code part (capybara_drivers.rb):

```
Capybara.register_driver :polt do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(
      app,
      js_errors: false, # break on js error
      timeout: 180, # maximum time in second for the server to produce a response
      debug: false, # more verbose log
      window_size: [1280, 800], # not responsive, used to simulate scroll when needed
      inspector: false, # use debug breakpoint and chrome inspector,
      phantomjs_options: ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--ssl-protocol=any', '--load-images=no', '--proxy=localhost:9050', '--proxy-type=socks5']

  )
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your production environment needs to make outbound connections through a socks5 proxy, and your other environments don't. You'll need to make the configuration dependent on environment

```
Capybara.register_driver :polt do |app|
  phantomjs_options = ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--ssl-protocol=any', '--load-images=no']
  phantomjs_options.push('--proxy=localhost:9050', '--proxy-type=socks5') if Rails.env.production?
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(
      app,
      js_errors: false, # break on js error
      timeout: 180, # maximum time in second for the server to produce a response
      debug: false, # more verbose log
      window_size: [1280, 800], # not responsive, used to simulate scroll when needed
      inspector: false, # use debug breakpoint and chrome inspector,
      phantomjs_options: phantomjs_options
  )
end
```

Comment: Can you please explain further why is this happening?

Comment: You are configuring the proxy options for phantomjs which tell it to make outgoing requests via a socks5 proxy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) at localhost:9050.  Whether or not that is actually required is dependent on your production environment, and you would need to talk to whoever is in charge of that.  You stated that it wasn't needed for dev and staging, so by not configuring the proxy in those environments phantomjs will just make all web requests directly.

Comment: I'm in charge of all of the project and you helped me solve the problem so thank you. Now I want to learn and understand the reason this is happening. Can you point me in the right direction please? I didn't state that it isn't needed for dev and staging, I just said it's not working for some reason and I want to know why

Comment: @MaxZXL I don't know how better to explain this to you - someone configured the driver to use a proxy on port 9050 (which is usually a Tor socks proxy) - maybe that isn't required or maybe it's trying to hide the ip your app is doing whatever it does from.  You aren't running that proxy on your local dev and staging machines so all outgoing requests there would fail if you configured a proxy in those environments